# OpenLayers2 Point was removed after draw Path

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to draw some paths  using OpenLayers.

Add new Layer

```
    var mLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("New Layer", {
        styleMap : new OpenLayers.StyleMap(markerStyle)
    });
    var editPanel = new DOU.EditingToolbar(mLayer);
    map.addLayer(mLayer);
    map.addControl(editPanel);
```

[image]

To draw Path, I use Path Control. But when I change control (Example, I click to Move Control or Point Control, all Markers (which you can see in the picture) will be removed.

Do you have any suggestion?

My Code:

```
DOU.HandlerPath = OpenLayers.Class(DOU.HandlerPoint, {

    /**
     * Property: line
     * {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>}
     */
    line : null,

    /**
     * APIProperty: maxVertices
     * {Number} The maximum number of vertices which can be drawn by this
     * handler. When the number of vertices reaches maxVertices, the
     * geometry is automatically finalized. Default is null.
     */
    maxVertices : null,

    /**
     * Property: doubleTouchTolerance
     * {Number} Maximum number of pixels between two touches for
     * the gesture to be considered a "finalize feature" action.
     * Default is 20.
     */
    doubleTouchTolerance : 20,

    /**
     * Property: freehand
     * {Boolean} In freehand mode, the handler starts the path on mouse down,
     * adds a point for every mouse move, and finishes the path on mouse up.
     * Outside of freehand mode, a point is added to the path on every mouse
     * click and double-click finishes the path.
     */
    freehand : false,

    /**
     * Property: freehandToggle
     * {String} If set, freehandToggle is checked on mouse events and will set
     * the freehand mode to the opposite of this.freehand. To disallow
     * toggling between freehand and non-freehand mode, set freehandToggle to
     * null. Acceptable toggle values are 'shiftKey', 'ctrlKey', and 'altKey'.
     */
    freehandToggle : 'shiftKey',

    /**
     * Property: timerId
     * {Integer} The timer used to test the double touch.
     */
    timerId : null,

    /**
     * Property: redoStack
     * {Array} Stack containing points removed with <undo>.
     */
    redoStack : null,

    /**
     * Constructor: OpenLayers.Handler.Path
     * Create a new path hander
     *
     * Parameters:
     * control - {<OpenLayers.Control>} The control that owns this handler
     * callbacks - {Object} An object with a properties whose values are
     * functions. Various callbacks described below.
     * options - {Object} An optional object with properties to be set on the
     * handler
     *
     * Named callbacks:
     * create - Called when a sketch is first created. Callback called with
     * the creation point geometry and sketch feature.
     * modify - Called with each move of a vertex with the vertex (point)
     * geometry and the sketch feature.
     * point - Called as each point is added. Receives the new point geometry.
     * done - Called when the point drawing is finished. The callback will
     * recieve a single argument, the linestring geometry.
     * cancel - Called when the handler is deactivated while drawing. The
     * cancel callback will receive a geometry.
     */

    /**
     * Method: createFeature
     * Add temporary geometries
     *
     * Parameters:
     * pixel - {<OpenLayers.Pixel>} The initial pixel location for the new
     * feature.
     */
    createFeature : function(pixel) {
        var lonlat = this.layer.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(pixel);
        var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);
        // this.point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry);
        this.point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, {}, DOU.PointStyle);
        this.line = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([this.point.geometry]), {}, DOU.LineStyle);

        this.callback("create", [this.point.geometry, this.getSketch(), this.ps]);
        this.point.geometry.clearBounds();
        this.layer.addFeatures([this.line, this.point], {
            // silent : true
        });
    },

    /**
     * Method: destroyFeature
     * Destroy temporary geometries
     *
     * Parameters:
     * force - {Boolean} Destroy even if persist is true.
     */
    destroyFeature : function(force) {
        //DOU.HandlerPoint.prototype.destroyFeature.call(this, force);
        this.line = null;
    },

    /**
     * Method: destroyPersistedFeature
     * Destroy the persisted feature.
     */
    destroyPersistedFeature : function() {
        var layer = this.layer;
        if (layer && layer.features.length > 2) {
            // this.layer.features[0].destroy();
        }
    },

    /**
     * Method: removePoint
     * Destroy the temporary point.
     */
    /*
    removePoint : function() {
    if (this.point) {
    this.layer.removeFeatures([this.point]);
    }
    },*/

    /**
     * Method: addPoint
     * Add point to geometry. Send the point index to override
     * the behavior of LinearRing that disregards adding duplicate points.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * pixel - {<OpenLayers.Pixel>} The pixel location for the new point.
     */
    addPoint : function(pixel) {
        //this.layer.removeFeatures([this.point]);
        var lonlat = this.layer.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(pixel);
        this.point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat));

        this.line.geometry.addComponent(this.point.geometry, this.line.geometry.components.length);

        this.layer.addFeatures([this.point]);

        this.callback("point", [this.point.geometry, this.getGeometry()]);
        this.callback("modify", [this.point.geometry, this.getSketch()]);
        this.drawFeature();
        delete this.redoStack;
    },

    /**
     * Method: insertXY
     * Insert a point in the current sketch given x & y coordinates. The new
     * point is inserted immediately before the most recently drawn point.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * x - {Number} The x-coordinate of the point.
     * y - {Number} The y-coordinate of the point.
     */
    insertXY : function(x, y) {
        this.line.geometry.addComponent(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(x, y), this.getCurrentPointIndex());
        this.drawFeature();
        delete this.redoStack;
    },

    /**
     * Method: insertDeltaXY
     * Insert a point given offsets from the previously inserted point.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * dx - {Number} The x-coordinate offset of the point.
     * dy - {Number} The y-coordinate offset of the point.
     */
    insertDeltaXY : function(dx, dy) {
        var previousIndex = this.getCurrentPointIndex() - 1;
        var p0 = this.line.geometry.components[previousIndex];
        if (p0 && !isNaN(p0.x) && !isNaN(p0.y)) {
            this.insertXY(p0.x + dx, p0.y + dy);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Method: insertDirectionLength
     * Insert a point in the current sketch given a direction and a length.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * direction - {Number} Degrees clockwise from the positive x-axis.
     * length - {Number} Distance from the previously drawn point.
     */
    insertDirectionLength : function(direction, length) {
        direction *= Math.PI / 180;
        var dx = length * Math.cos(direction);
        var dy = length * Math.sin(direction);
        this.insertDeltaXY(dx, dy);
    },

    /**
     * Method: insertDeflectionLength
     * Insert a point in the current sketch given a deflection and a length.
     * The deflection should be degrees clockwise from the previously
     * digitized segment.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * deflection - {Number} Degrees clockwise from the previous segment.
     * length - {Number} Distance from the previously drawn point.
     */
    insertDeflectionLength : function(deflection, length) {
        var previousIndex = this.getCurrentPointIndex() - 1;
        if (previousIndex > 0) {
            var p1 = this.line.geometry.components[previousIndex];
            var p0 = this.line.geometry.components[previousIndex - 1];
            var theta = Math.atan2(p1.y - p0.y, p1.x - p0.x);
            this.insertDirectionLength((theta * 180 / Math.PI) + deflection, length);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Method: getCurrentPointIndex
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Number} The index of the most recently drawn point.
     */
    getCurrentPointIndex : function() {
        return this.line.geometry.components.length - 1;
    },

    /**
     * Method: undo
     * Remove the most recently added point in the sketch geometry.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} A point was removed.
     */
    undo : function() {
        var geometry = this.line.geometry;
        var components = geometry.components;
        var index = this.getCurrentPointIndex() - 1;
        var target = components[index];
        var undone = geometry.removeComponent(target);
        if (undone) {
            // On touch devices, set the current ("mouse location") point to
            // match the last digitized point.
            if (this.touch && index > 0) {
                components = geometry.components;
                // safety
                var lastpt = components[index - 1];
                var curptidx = this.getCurrentPointIndex();
                var curpt = components[curptidx];
                curpt.x = lastpt.x;
                curpt.y = lastpt.y;
            }
            if (!this.redoStack) {
                this.redoStack = [];
            }
            this.redoStack.push(target);
            this.drawFeature();
        }
        return undone;
    },

    /**
     * Method: redo
     * Reinsert the most recently removed point resulting from an <undo> call.
     * The undo stack is deleted whenever a point is added by other means.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} A point was added.
     */
    redo : function() {
        var target = this.redoStack && this.redoStack.pop();
        if (target) {
            this.line.geometry.addComponent(target, this.getCurrentPointIndex());
            this.drawFeature();
        }
        return !!target;
    },

    /**
     * Method: freehandMode
     * Determine whether to behave in freehand mode or not.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean}
     */
    freehandMode : function(evt) {
        return (this.freehandToggle && evt[this.freehandToggle]) ? !this.freehand : this.freehand;
    },

    /**
     * Method: modifyFeature
     * Modify the existing geometry given the new point
     *
     * Parameters:
     * pixel - {<OpenLayers.Pixel>} The updated pixel location for the latest
     * point.
     * drawing - {Boolean} Indicate if we're currently drawing.
     */
    modifyFeature : function(pixel, drawing) {
        if (!this.line) {
            this.createFeature(pixel);
        }
        var lonlat = this.layer.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(pixel);
        this.point.geometry.x = lonlat.lon;
        this.point.geometry.y = lonlat.lat;

        this.callback("modify", [this.point.geometry, this.getSketch(), drawing]);
        this.point.geometry.clearBounds();
        this.drawFeature();
    },

    /**
     * Method: drawFeature
     * Render geometries on the temporary layer.
     */
    drawFeature : function() {
        this.layer.drawFeature(this.line, this.style);
        this.layer.drawFeature(this.point, this.style);
    },

    /**
     * Method: getSketch
     * Return the sketch feature.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>}
     */
    getSketch : function() {
        return this.line;
    },

    /**
     * Method: getGeometry
     * Return the sketch geometry. If <multi> is true, this will return
     * a multi-part geometry.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {<OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString>}
     */
    getGeometry : function() {
        var geometry = this.line && this.line.geometry;
        if (geometry && this.multi) {
            geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiLineString([geometry]);
        }
        return geometry;
    },

    /**
     * method: touchstart
     * handle touchstart.
     *
     * parameters:
     * evt - {event} the browser event
     *
     * returns:
     * {boolean} allow event propagation
     */
    touchstart : function(evt) {
        if (this.timerId && this.passesTolerance(this.lastTouchPx, evt.xy, this.doubleTouchTolerance)) {
            // double-tap, finalize the geometry
            this.finishGeometry();
            window.clearTimeout(this.timerId);
            this.timerId = null;
            return false;
        } else {
            if (this.timerId) {
                window.clearTimeout(this.timerId);
                this.timerId = null;
            }
            this.timerId = window.setTimeout(OpenLayers.Function.bind(function() {
                this.timerId = null;
            }, this), 300);
            return DOU.HandlerPoint.prototype.touchstart.call(this, evt);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Method: down
     * Handle mousedown and touchstart. Add a new point to the geometry and
     * render it. Return determines whether to propagate the event on the map.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} The browser event
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} Allow event propagation
     */
    down : function(evt) {
        var stopDown = this.stopDown;
        if (this.freehandMode(evt)) {
            stopDown = true;
            if (this.touch) {
                this.modifyFeature(evt.xy, !!this.lastUp);
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
            }
        }
        if (!this.touch && (!this.lastDown || !this.passesTolerance(this.lastDown, evt.xy, this.pixelTolerance))) {
            this.modifyFeature(evt.xy, !!this.lastUp);
        }
        this.mouseDown = true;
        this.lastDown = evt.xy;
        this.stoppedDown = stopDown;
        return !stopDown;
    },

    /**
     * Method: move
     * Handle mousemove and touchmove. Adjust the geometry and redraw.
     * Return determines whether to propagate the event on the map.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} The browser event
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} Allow event propagation
     */
    move : function(evt) {
        if (this.stoppedDown && this.freehandMode(evt)) {
            if (this.persist) {
                this.destroyPersistedFeature();
            }
            if (this.maxVertices && this.line && this.line.geometry.components.length === this.maxVertices) {
                //this.removePoint();
                this.finalize();
            } else {
                this.addPoint(evt.xy);
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.touch && (!this.mouseDown || this.stoppedDown)) {
            this.modifyFeature(evt.xy, !!this.lastUp);
        }
        return true;
    },

    /**
     * Method: up
     * Handle mouseup and touchend. Send the latest point in the geometry to
     * the control. Return determines whether to propagate the event on the map.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} The browser event
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} Allow event propagation
     */
    up : function(evt) {
        if (this.mouseDown && (!this.lastUp || !this.lastUp.equals(evt.xy))) {
            if (this.stoppedDown && this.freehandMode(evt)) {
                if (this.persist) {
                    this.destroyPersistedFeature();
                }
                //this.removePoint();
                this.finalize();
            } else {
                if (this.passesTolerance(this.lastDown, evt.xy, this.pixelTolerance)) {
                    if (this.touch) {
                        this.modifyFeature(evt.xy);
                    }
                    if (this.lastUp == null && this.persist) {
                        this.destroyPersistedFeature();
                    }
                    this.addPoint(evt.xy);
                    this.lastUp = evt.xy;
                    if (this.line.geometry.components.length === this.maxVertices + 1) {
                        this.finishGeometry();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.stoppedDown = this.stopDown;
        this.mouseDown = false;
        return !this.stopUp;
    },

    /**
     * APIMethod: finishGeometry
     * Finish the geometry and send it back to the control.
     */
    finishGeometry : function() {
        var index = this.line.geometry.components.length - 1;
        this.line.geometry.removeComponent(this.line.geometry.components[index]);
        //this.removePoint();
        this.finalize();
    },

    /**
     * Method: dblclick
     * Handle double-clicks.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} The browser event
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} Allow event propagation
     */
    dblclick : function(evt) {
        if (!this.freehandMode(evt)) {
            this.finishGeometry();
        }
        return false;
    },

    CLASS_NAME : "OpenLayers.Handler.Path"
});

DOU.EditingToolbar = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control.Panel, {

    /**
     * APIProperty: citeCompliant
     * {Boolean} If set to true, coordinates of features drawn in a map extent
     * crossing the date line won't exceed the world bounds. Default is false.
     */
    citeCompliant : false,

    /**
     * Constructor: OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar
     * Create an editing toolbar for a given layer.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * layer - {<OpenLayers.Layer.Vector>}
     * options - {Object}
     */
    initialize : function(layer, options) {
        OpenLayers.Control.Panel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);

        this.addControls([new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()]);
        var controls = [new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer, DOU.HandlerPoint, {
            displayClass : 'olControlDrawFeaturePoint',
            handlerOptions : {
                citeCompliant : this.citeCompliant
            }
        }), new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer, DOU.HandlerPath, {
            displayClass : 'olControlDrawFeaturePath',
            handlerOptions : {
                citeCompliant : this.citeCompliant
            }
        })];
        this.addControls(controls);
    },

    /**
     * Method: draw
     * calls the default draw, and then activates mouse defaults.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {DOMElement}
     */
    draw : function() {
        var div = OpenLayers.Control.Panel.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.defaultControl === null) {
            this.defaultControl = this.controls[0];
        }
        return div;
    },

    CLASS_NAME : "OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar"
});
```

Comment: Does it work without the ```this.point.geometry.clearBounds();``` call?

Comment: :D No. I try to remove this.point.geometry.clearBounds(); But, nothing changes. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
I want to share you the way to resolve if you get the same problem.

In this time. I added the lines and the points in the same layer.

```
 this.layer.addFeatures([this.point]);
 this.layer.addFeatures([this.line]);
```

No no. May be it is not available. So when I try to add points to other layer. It works fine.

```
 this.layer.addFeatures([this.point]);
 this.otherLayer.addFeatures([this.line]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work (we need  DOU.HandlerPoint). Are you adding the vector layer to the map?

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapOptions);
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OSM', ["http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png","http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png","http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],{transitionEffect: 'resize'});   
map.addLayer(osm);

var lyr =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");
var control = new DOU.EditingToolbar(lyr);
map.addLayer(lyr); // Be sure to add the vector layer to the map
map.addControl(lyr);
```

Comment: Yes. I added layer to map. :(

Comment: Could you post a full example? It works for me :)

Comment: I update my question